# Timeout when connecting Java app to new version of postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, ibm-cloud

I have a legacy app that is currently working with Postgres9 that I have to migrate to postgres12.
I did the dump the old database and restored it to the new one without issues.

But when I tried to connect my legacy app with the new database the app never connects.

In the past, my POM was:

```
<!-- Postgresql Database Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1211.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
```

and now (after checking that the old version was not working I tried to did some update here):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

In my properties I have:

```
jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx:XXXX/db_name
jdbc.username=db_user
jdbc.password=xxxxx
```

Before I was using a postgres installed in a server, but now, I'm using a Database for postgres from IBM Cloud (I supossed this should not generate any issue). Similar to RDS from AWS.

So when I tried to run my app I got tomcat timeout. I increased the timeout to 120 but I'm still getting that error...

Exactly same configuration on Dbeaver works like a charm.
I tried with that version of the driver but same behavior (the one for org.postgres)

[image]

Comment: Looks like a network configuration problem.

Comment: Are you sure you use correct endpoint (private/public)? Private endpoint will be available only from "the cloud" not externally.